# Is there a way to change a global variable on the document in the call back xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, jquery-templates

I am pretty new to the AJAX thing, but now  I want to set some value to a global variable on the document based on status changed in the call back function xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange, I used something like

```
function checkFile(fileUrl) {
    var xmlHttpReq = false;
    var self = this;
        // Mozilla/Safari
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    // IE
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    if(self.xmlHttpReq == null){
    alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTPReq")
    }

    self.xmlHttpReq.open('HEAD', fileUrl, true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
            if (self.xmlHttpReq.status == 200) { 
         window.rett = 1;
        //alert(window.rett);
           } else if (self.xmlHttpReq.status == 404) { 
         window.rett = 0;
        //alert(window.rett);
            }
        }
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.send(); 
}
```

and I use the `checkFile` in a jquery template like this:

```
<script id="resultTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
        <li> ${checkFile(link)} <b> {{if window.rett ==  1 }} ${link}   {{/if}}</b> </li> 
    </script>
```

but when I access the `window.rett` in a Jquery template, it says undefined...

The reason I want to get the global value is that I want to generate different GUI based on the global value.

Maybe this is not a good practice of using global variable? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Is it only a success and error scenario that you want to render different?

Comment: @SHANK I think maybe not. I just learnt the stuff today, and is trying to build things up, and when I came across this problem....

Comment: You just edited your code to use an event? Does the alert in your event handler fire on the correct time?

Comment: yeah, every time it said undefined.

Comment: @WouterdeKort My bad. I just tested, not every time undefined. But since it is asynchronous  call, when i used it in the template, it is always undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely because by the time you tried accessing it, the AJAX request has not completed yet (has not reached state 4), thus your global hasn't been declared (or if it was, it still contains the value of the previous result)

I suggest you use your template from within the callback. That way, by the time your template checks for the value, the value is already there:

```
function yourAjaxFunction(arg1, arg2,...,callback){

  //all AJAX setup codes here

  if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState === 4) {
    if (self.xmlHttpReq.status === 200) { 
      //sending the callback a 1
      callback(1);
    } else if (self.xmlHttpReq.status === 404) { 
      //sending the callback a 1
      callback(0);
    }
  }

  //AJAX send codes

}

//how you should use it
yourAjaxFunction(arg1,arg2,...,function(rett){
  //use rett here
  //parse template here
});
```

Comment: Does this approach can work in the senario if my original `yourAjaxFunction` is used in this way? 
`<script id="resultTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
   <li> <b> {{if yourAjaxFunction(link) ==  1 }} ${link}   {{/if}}</b> </li> 
 </script>`

Comment: @monica then it's best you include **all** related code. Also, AJAX isn't a synchronous operation (not sequential/procedural). Better [read mode about AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX)

Comment: Thanks for the link! and all related code is listed in update.